# What actually occurs when stating "private"/"protected" in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, access-specifier

What is actually occurring when `private`/`protected` is stated within a Ruby class definition? They are not [keywords](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/), so that implies they must be method calls, but I cannot find where they are defined. They do not appear to be documented. Are the two different ways of declaring `private`/`protected` methods (shown below) implemented differently? (The second way is obviously a method call, but this is not so apparent in the first way.)

```
class Foo
  private
  def i_am_private; end
  def so_am_i; end
end

class Foo
  def i_am_private; end
  def so_am_i; end
  private :i_am_private, :so_am_i
end
```

Comment: Have you looked at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Classes#Private ?

Comment: Yes but this doesn't state where or how the methods are actually implemented. I'm fully aware of *what* `private` & `protected` do, I'm curious about Ruby's internals (the *how* & *where*).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both are method calls. Quoting from [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/language.html#accesscontrol):

> Each function can be used in two different ways.
>
> 1. If used with no arguments, the three functions set the default access control of subsequently defined methods.
> 2. With arguments, the functions set the access control of the named methods and constants.

See documentation here:

1. [Module.private](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/ref_c_module.html#Module.private)
2. [Access Control](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/language.html#accesscontrol)

You were looking for how the `Module.private` method comes into existence. [Here is where that happens](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_9_3_194/vm_method.c#L1043). And [here is some more information](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_9_3_194/README.EXT#L351) about it. You would have to read more into it, starting from `rb_define_private_method` defined in `class.c`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm curious why this doesn't show up here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Module.html

Comment: I agree it should be there, but I don't know why it's not. I don't really like the documentation too much - it could be improved a lot!

Comment: Do you know where the method is actually defined though? That's part of what I'm really looking for. I figured it'd probably be in `class.c` but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: These are instance methods of the Module class. All classes are modules, and inside a class definition (but outside method definitions), self refers to class being defined. Thus, public, private, and protected may be used bare as if they were keywords of the language - they behaves like 'Mimic methods'. For example, try following code `Module.private_methods.each { |m| puts m if m =~ /private|protected/ }`

Comment: I think its not in docs because that method is "private to module" and seemingly the docs are only listing public methods.

Comment: I can't find it either, still looking.

Comment: Awesome, that's what I was looking for. Sad that it's not well documented and buried away in `vm_method.c`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add something about their *keyword-like* behavior, because the answers have been more about *where* than *how*; the answer lies in the complex metaprogramming capabilities of Ruby.
It is possible to use them as *keywords* making use of the `method_added` hook; an hook in Ruby is a function that is called when a specific event (i.e. the hook's name) occurs.
What's important is that the `method_added` hook receives as his argument the name of the method that has been defined: this way, it's possible to modify it's behavior.

For example, you could use this hook to define a behavior similar to Python's *decorators*; the important part is that, differently from the `private` and `protected` methods, this decorator-like method should define a `method_added` that undefines itself:

```
class Module
  def simple_decorator
    eigenclass = class << self; self; end
    eigenclass.class_eval do
      define_method :method_added do |name|
        eigenclass.class_eval { remove_method :method_added }
        old_name = 'old_' + name.to_s
        alias_method old_name, name
        class_eval %Q{
          def #{name}(*args, &block)
            p 'Do something before call...'
            #{old_name}(*args, &block)
            p '... and something after call.'
          end
        }
      end
    end
  end
end

class UsefulClass
  simple_decorator
  def print_something
    p "I'm a decorated method :)"
  end

  def print_something_else
    p "I'm not decorated :("
  end
end

a = UsefulClass.new
a.print_something
a.print_something_else
```

`simple_decorator` looks like a language keyword and behaves like `private`; however, because it removes the `method_added` hook, it only applies to the immediately following method definition.

Comment: I pity the poor fellow who would have to maintain such code. Just because you can, doesn't mean you should.