# Calling One Private class method with another of same class

Tags: ruby

```
class Person
  def self.first_name
    puts "this is the first_name"
    second_name
  end
  private
  def self.second_name
    third_name
  end
  def self.third_name
    puts "this is the third name"
  end
end
```

how to make self.second_name call the self.third_name in the private methods

Comment: Is there a reason why you're defining the private methods as class methods i.e. `def self.xxxx` rather than instance methods i.e. `def xxxx`?

Comment: Please take a moment to read https://stackoverflow.com/q/4952980/3784008 as your code does not work the way you think it does.

Answer (score 3):

The method [Module#private](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Module.html#method-i-private), in the body of a method, on a line by itself, causes all *instances methods* defined thereafter to be `private` until and if the method [Module#public](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Module.html#method-i-public) or [Module#protected](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Module.html#method-i-protected) appears on a line by itself<sup>1</sup>. Class method definitions are unaffected.

Here are three ways to make a class method private.

**#1. Use the method [Module#private_class_method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Module.html#method-i-private_class_method) to make a public class method private**

```
class Klass
  def self.class_meth1
    '#1'
  end
  private_class_method(:class_meth1)
end
```

```
Klass.class_meth1
  #=> NoMethodError (private method `class_meth1' called for Klass:Class)
Klass.send(:class_meth1)
  #=> "#1" 
Klass.singleton_class.private_method_defined?(:class_meth1)
  #=> true
```

Private instance methods in a class' singleton class are private class methods. See [Object#singleton_class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Object.html#method-i-singleton_class) and [Module#private_method_defined?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Module.html#method-i-private_method_defined-3F).

**#2. Define an instance method in the class' singleton class following the keyword `private`**

```
class Klass
  class << self
    private
    def class_meth2
      '#2'
    end 
  end
end
```

```
Klass.singleton_class.private_method_defined?(:class_meth2)
  #=> true
```

**#3. Include the keyword `private` in-line when defining an instance method in the class' singleton class**

```
class Klass
  class << self
    private def class_meth3
      '#3'
    end 
  end
end
```

```
Klass.singleton_class.private_method_defined?(:class_meth3)
  #=> true
```

Note that `private` has no effect in the following, which creates a public class method:

```
class Klass
  private def self.class_meth
  end
end
```

**Calling a private class method**

In view of the foregoing discussion, this is what you need.

```
class Person
  def self.first_name
    puts "this is the first_name"
    second_name  
  end
  class << self
    private
    def second_name
      third_name
    end
    def third_name
      puts "this is the third name"
    end
  end
end
```

```
Person.first_name
this is the first_name
this is the third name
```

<sup>1. `Module#private` on a line by itself is of course disregarded if an instance method is defined with `public` or `protected` *inline* (e.g., `public def meth...`)</sup>.