# How to improve lisibility/split "fat" class method (inside ruby class/rails model)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

as a new Rubyist, I'm running into a recurring problem when it comes to structure my models.

**When a method is too long:**

1. I try to refactor to a better/shorter syntax
2. I try to split some parts into "sub methods"

**PROBLEM: I don't know how to split the method properly + whith which tool (private method, modules etc.)**

For example:

I need to run `Foo.main_class_method`

My model looks like this:

```
class Foo < Applicationrecord
  def self.main_class_method
    [...] # way too long method with nasty iterations
  end
end
```

I try to split my method to improve lisibility. It becomes :

```
class Foo < Applicationrecord
  def self.main_class_method
    [...] # fewer code
    self.first_splitted_class_method
    self.second_splitted_class_method
  end

  private
  def self.first_splitted_class_method
    [...] # some code
  end

  def self.second_splitted_class_method
    [...] # some code
  end
end
```

**Result: It works, but I fell like this is not the proper way to do it + I have side effects**

- **expected:** splitted_methods are not accessible, except inside `main_class_method`
- **got:** I can call `Foo.first_splitted_class_method` since class methods "ignore" Private. splitted_class_methods under `Private` are not private

**Question: Is it an acceptable way to split `main_class_method` or is it a complete misuse of private method ?**

Comment: There are no magic rules that make code good or bad. Is splitting a big method into smaller private method accepted? Yes. But what you really need here is a code review and stackoverflow is not the site for that. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Adding to what @max said: You can create private class methods, it just works a little differently, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952980/how-to-create-a-private-class-method

Comment: Visibility is really just one small part of the question. If you have a fat model you might want to ask yourself if what you are doing belongs inside the model. Models have tons of responsibilities (validations, database bindings, i18n, assocations) etc. So if you are doing the typical stuff that makes a model fat like importing data from an API, CSV or somewhere you should consider moving that into an object that just does that job instead of making the model into more of a god object. Just because the class is named User does not mean that it has to do everything user related.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I fixed the not private "side effect" with private_class_method :method_name.
I know visibility is more a consequence than a problem itself.
Little by little, I'm trying to use the right tools to comply with DRY, SOLID etc. principles.
Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

1. **Using private method to split your code:**

   - Possible but not the real solution if the code belongs somewhere else
   - It's rather about "does it belongs here?" than "does it look nicer?"
2. **To fix the "not private" private class method ([original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952980/how-to-create-a-private-class-method)) :**

   - use `private_class_method :your_method_name` after you defined it
   - or right before

```
private_class_method def your_method_name
  [...] # your code
end
```

3. **If your splitting a class/instance method:**

   - the splitted_method must be the same type(class/instance) as the main_class_method calling it
   - In the main_method you can call the splitted_method with or without using self.method syntax

```
class Foo < Applicationrecord
  def self.main_class_method
    # Here, self == Foo class
    # first_splitted_class == class method, I can call self.first_splitted_class_method 
    self.first_splitted_class_method
    # I can also call directly without self because self is implicit
    second_splitted_class_method
  end

  def self.first_splitted_class_method
  end

  def self.second_splitted_class_method
  end

  private_class_method :first_splitted_class_method, :second_splitted_class_method
end
```